# how to add validation for angular material from inputs

Tags: angular-material

I have two input fields.

HTML:

```
       <mat-form-field class="example-form-field" >
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="First Name" name = "user_first_name" [(ngModel)]="user_first_name" required>
        <button mat-button *ngIf="user_first_name" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="user_first_name=''">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>


      <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name = "user_last_name" [(ngModel)]="user_last_name" required>
        <button mat-button *ngIf="user_last_name" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="user_last_name=''">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Here is my requirements for input validation.

1. if the user enters anything starts with these "@!#$%^7*().,;:'"'/?=-+][{}\|" I want to display a message like Please enter valid data.
2. If the user is not entering anything in inputs I want to display like "First Name is required".

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Please read about how to use `formcontrol` you will be easily able to add these validations to your form fields.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is example from material doc https://stackblitz.com/angular/dgbrbgmgpel
And for your case need also add Pattern Validator https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator